# How to make textView track how many enemy's eliminated?

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to be able to make a textview appear in my game and it tells you how many enemy's have been killed. My game uses Cocos2D lib. For example I touch somewhere on screen and it shoots a bullet from the left side of the screen(my character is on the left side) and the enemy's come from the right. When a bullet and enemy collides they dissapear and that should count as one kill and the textview should say "1 Kill". I don'tknow how to do this. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should have shown what have you tried first. But still I'll try to show the path way:

Step 1: Google how to create a `TextView`.

Step 2: When the event of collision of the bullet and enemy happens, maintain a counter variable that increments with each collision event.

Step 3: Display the value of the counter in the TextView.

Please do mention that at what point are you stuck. First try researching. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm stuck in step 2, not sure what your trying to say. I already know how to make a text view but I don't know how to make it show how many projectiles/enemies have collided.(Making that kills)

Comment: Quick question: How are you detecting when a collision has occurred?

Comment: Can you give me an example, I am detecting the collisions by using    "targetsToDelete"

Comment: if `targetsToDelete` is an array, then just get the length of the array( the number of elements in it). That number can be used inside text view. On other hand if their exist any function which gets called every time a collision occurs, then increment a global variable everytime that function is called. Use that number inside text view.

Comment: Could you make a sample code I still don't understand what that means(I am a slow learner so it took me a long time to look for help and make this game).Just give me a really simple code of(anything related to this)what your telling me

Comment: Its alright. Everyone learns at their own rate. I'll try to get back to you soon. :)